# emacs org-mode, can't set custom TODO sequence

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I want to define a custom sequence for the TODO feature of org-mode.

So I added this to the very top of the file (first column):

```
#+SEQ_TODO: TODO TEST DONE
```

Finally, when I pressed `C-c C-t`, the sequence wasnt appearing, it was just the normal `TODO-->Done--->blank` sequence.

Why wasn't my custom sequence used?

My `org-agenda-files` is set to:

```
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/Documents/org"))
```

Further tries:

1. I tried to run `C-c \`, this gave my the "Match:" prompt at the bottom, but didn't return any matched results.

   `C-c \ runs the command org-match-sparse-tree, which is an interactive
   compiled Lisp function in org.el'.`

   I have a feeiling that `C-c \` not returning any matches might indicate some underlying problem. A problem that might cause the "sequence instruction" on top not to be parsed?
2. Then I run `C-c [` which is mapped to:

   `C-c [ runs the command org-agenda-file-to-front, which is an
   interactive compiled Lisp function in org.el'.`

   This re-parses the .org file. Didn't change anything.

So again, how can I defined a custom TODO-sequence?

And also as a secondary question, why isn't `C-c \` working?

I can run `C-c a`, which is agenda-mode, from which I can do what `C-c \`does, but I'm curious to know.

Thanks in advance for your time and kind concern.

Jenia

Comment: Works for me.  Org mode should read it when you visit the file/buffer, so if you've put that at the top of the buffer and have not yet saved/reopened it, either do that, or re-enter org mode (via `M-x org-mode`) on that buffer.  Does it work now?

Comment: You may already be doing this -- when using a directory for the `org-agenda-files` variable, the files being used must end in `.org` -- or you can modify `org-agenda-file-regexp` to add additional file extensions.  If you haven't restarted Emacs after modifying your configuration, then go ahead and do so.  Check your `org-agenda-files` variable configuration with:  `M-x eval-expression RET (org-agenda-files) RET`

Comment: If you're doing a buffer-local sequence via `#+SEQ_TODO: TODO TEST DONE` at the top, it doesn't matter what's in your `org-agenda-files` or what the file extension is (except insofar as *.org files automatically open in `org-mode` upon visiting).  The buffer only needs to be in `org-mode`, set either automatically or manually.

Answer (score 6):

This might be too obvious to need saying, but have you tried `C-c C-c` with point on the `#+SEQ_TODO` line?